# TYPO3 6.2 scaling img using gifbuilder did't work

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, typoscript, yag

After upgrading TYPO3 from version 6.2.9 to 6.2.10 the scaling images using GIFBUILDER didn't work. When I'm testing image processing in Instal Tool everything looks ok, byt when I want to change img using GIFBUILDER scaling img didn't work. My actual configuration looks like this:

```
'GFX' => array(
    'colorspace' => 'sRGB',
    'gdlib_png' => '1',
    'im' => '1',
    'im_mask_temp_ext_gif' => '1',
    'im_noFramePrepended' => '1',
    'im_noScaleUp' => '0',
    'im_path' => '/usr/local/bin/',
    'im_path_lzw' => '/usr/local/bin/',
    'im_stripProfileCommand' => '-strip',
    'im_v5effects' => '-1',
    'im_version_5' => 'im6',
    'image_processing' => '1',
    'jpg_quality' => '70',
    'thumbnails' => '1',
    'thumbnails_png' => '1',
),
```

And code who works "yesterday" looks like that:

```
plugin.tx_yag.settings.themes.default {
  resolutionConfigs {

        thumb >
        thumb = GIFBUILDER
        thumb {
            XY = [10.w],[10.h]

            format = jpg
            quality = 60

            10 = IMAGE
            10 {
            file.maxW >
            file.maxH >
            file.width = 380c
            file.height = 240c
            file.width.override.field = imagewidth
            file.height.override.field = imageheight
            file.import.field = yagImage
            }
        }

      albumThumb < plugin.tx_yag.settings.themes.default.resolutionConfigs.thumb
      galleryThumb < plugin.tx_yag.settings.themes.default.resolutionConfigs.thumb

        medium >
        medium = GIFBUILDER
        medium {
            XY = [10.w],[10.h]

            format = jpg
            quality = 65

            10 = IMAGE
            10 {
            file.maxW = 783
            file.maxH = 600
            file.import.field = yagImage
            }

            // Load watermark image file
            20 = IMAGE
            20 {
               file = fileadmin/media/watermark_logo.png

               // Center the watermark image (for a watermark size of 100x100px): offset = [10.w]/2-50,[10.h]/2-50
               offset = [10.w]-190,[10.h]-40
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Every images generated by previous code cropping original image to maxW and maxH dimension, but not scaling, so I have only 1/4 of each img.

Any ideas what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this issue was posted on forge https://forge.typo3.org/issues/65378.

If so, I think you should add your comments to the this thread. This will speed up reaction of TYPO3 team.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that bug on forge